# What's the SQL idiom for zipping — in the functional sense — two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, if I have a set of classes and a set of classrooms, and I want to pair the two up with some arbitrary pairing:

```
> SELECT class_name FROM classes ORDER BY class_name
Calculus
English
History
> SELECT room_name FROM classrooms ORDER BY room_name
Room 101
Room 102
Room 201
```

I'd like to "zip" them like this:

```
> SELECT class_name FROM classes ORDER … ZIP SELECT room_name FROM classrooms ORDER …
Calculus | Room 101
English  | Room 102
History  | Room 201
```

Currently I'm dealing with MySQL… but possibly — optimistically? — there is a reasonably standards compliant way to do this?

Comment: It looks like a join, but it's not clear by what criteria.

Comment: Currently I'm dealing with MySQL, but I'd like to know if there's any general way to do this (since I generally deal with PostgreSQL, and occasionally SQLite too).

Comment: You will have to use a query on more than one table using a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) between them.

Comment: The join criteria is the "index in the result set".

Comment: (Rolled back edits by Nicholas — I feel like they made things less readable, and I'm going to be showing this question around to friends,  so this readability is important)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it in MySql

```
SELECT c.class_name, r.room_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT class_name, @n := @n + 1 rnum
    FROM classes CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
   ORDER BY class_name
) c JOIN
(
  SELECT room_name, @m := @m + 1 rnum
    FROM classrooms CROSS JOIN (SELECT @m := 0) i
   ORDER BY room_name
) r 
   ON c.rnum = r.rnum
```

Output:

```
| CLASS_NAME | ROOM_NAME |
-------------|-----------|
|   Calculus |  Room 101 |
|    English |  Room 102 |
|    History |  Room 201 |
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/414ae/4)** demo

---

Same thing in Postgres will look like

```
SELECT c.class_name, r.room_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT class_name, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY class_name) rnum
    FROM classes 
) c JOIN
(
  SELECT room_name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY room_name) rnum
    FROM classrooms 
) r 
   ON c.rnum = r.rnum
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/145b5/1)** demo

---

And in SQLite

```
SELECT c.class_name, r.room_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT class_name, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM classes 
           WHERE c.class_name >= class_name) rnum
    FROM classes c
) c JOIN
(
  SELECT room_name,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM classrooms 
           WHERE r.room_name >= room_name) rnum
    FROM classrooms r
) r 
   ON c.rnum = r.rnum
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/145b5/5)** demo

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of `join`, but you need to create the join key.  Alas, though, this requires a `full outer join`, because you do not know which list is longer.

So, you can do this by using variables to enumerate the rows and then using `union all` and `group by` to get the values:

```
select max(case when which = 'class' then name end) as class_name,
       max(case when which = 'room' then name end) as room_name
from ((SELECT class_name as name, @rnc := @rnc + 1 as rn, 'class' as which
       FROM classes cross join
            (select @rnc := 0) const
       ORDER BY class_name
      ) union all
      (select room_name, @rnr := @rnr + 1 as rn, 'room'
       from classrooms cross join
            (select @rnr := 0) const
       ORDER BY room_name
      )
     ) t
group by rn;
```